# Could not find stored procedure ''

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to send my SQL DB a query as a stored procedure. It's not really stored in the DB, I'm creating it on the fly. Here is the code (excuse my VB):

```
Dim idOfChosenRecord As Integer = {Some value}
Dim myQuery As String  "SELECT [field] FROM [myDB].[myTable] WHERE [id]=@id"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnectionInitializedAndOpen)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", idOfChosenRecord))
Dim Reader As SqlDataReader = cmdView.ExecuteReader()
```

A similar function is running well right before my code (only it's calling a real stored procedure), and all over the module, as a matter of fact.
The difference is I'm trying to create the query on the spot.

The error message is the strange title of this question:
`Could not find stored procedure ''` - caught on the last line of the above code.

How would this be fixed (preferably without digging into the DB itself...)?

tx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

with

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

The problem is that you specified that you want to call stored procedure when in fact you have just a query. So you should specify that this is a query.

Comment: Thank you. I copied it from another place, I guess it doesn't work there either...

Comment: Yes, of course. Even omitting it works, I suppose this is default.

Answer (score 0):

You should change :

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

To

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. You can't create stored procedure on the fly. Once you choose the `CommandType.StoredProcedure` then it will expect you to pass the procedure name in `myQuery`. So you have to use `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

A Stored Procedure is different from running a text query (like you're doing here).